# How do I deploy a web application using F# to Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, f#, asp.net-mvc-4

When I deploy my web application to an Azure Web Site, I am getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have encountered this in the past when deploying to an IIS server and fixed it by installing the F# redistributable http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13450

Does anyone know what I can do to get this working on an Azure Web Site (not an Azure Web Role)?

Also, I do have Copy Local set to true for the FSharp.Core library from where it is being referenced.

Comment: Is your web application itself F#, or is it a C# template with an F# library doing most of the work? If the latter, the C# project needs to reference FSharp.Core directly. (I use F# + Azure regularly, and this is the most I've ever had to do to get it to work.)

Comment: That was the piece I was missing. Because I had installed the redistributable I didn't need to reference FSharp.Core in the web project. It was only referenced in library being referenced by my web project. Once I referenced FSharp.Core in my web project and set Copy Local to true, it worked.

If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Reposting from comment:</sub>

In my experience, in order to use an F# library from a C# project in Azure, it is necessary to reference `FSharp.Core` directly from the C# project in order for the proper assemblies to be uploaded. With C#-to-C# project references the 'Copy Local' property seems to propagate correctly, whereas with C#-to-F# references it does not.

I assume compiling with the [`--standalone` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) probably works as well, but I haven't tried it personally.