# Deployment of a web application using FSharp.Data to Azure Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, f#, azure-web-app-service

This is a similar question to [How do I deploy a web application using F# to Azure Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095818/how-do-i-deploy-a-web-application-using-f-to-azure-web-site).  My C#/F# MVC project uses the FSharp.Data NuGet package, and the deployment process fails with the message

Could not locate the assembly "FSharp.Data, Version=1.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

The only effective workaround I can see is to replace all of the NuGet references (FSharp.Data, FSharp.Data.DesignTime, FSharp.Data.Experimental, FSharp.Data.Experimental.DesignTime) with explicit references to the DLLs, and Copy Local set to true.  I am loath to throw the NuGet baby out with the bathwater in this way.  Is there a cleverer way?  Alternatively, is there an open issue to which I can add my vote?

Comment: Does this blog post help? http://sireel-world.azurewebsites.net/sir-eel-visions/WATK-FS-Pt2. There are a couple of issues with the F# project template that makes git deployment a bit tricky. If you are still having issues, it'd be great if you could create an issue here - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/new and perhaps push a sample repository that fails to GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Pranav.  I'll upload selected highlights of my project soon.  You probably wouldn't want to wade through all of the boring details of the project as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [<dependentAssembly>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ash1ksb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element to your `web.config` to make sure the `FSharp.Data` assembly is included when your project is deployed to Azure. I've used this technique before when deploying mixed F#/C# ASP.NET MVC projects to Azure; it's been a while, but I don't think I had to change the `Copy Local` setting on the referenced assemblies (which I added via NuGet).

Anyway, the entry you need to add should look something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Data" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

Based on Rob's comment that he's still getting the same error message, here're the next steps I would take to diagnose the issue.

- Build the Azure deployment package (you don't need to deploy it). When it's finished building, find the deployment package file (`*.cspkg`); this is actually just a zip file, so extract the contents into a folder, e.g., with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). In the extracted folder, there should be one file with the `*.cssx` extension which is much larger than the others; it's also a zip file, so extract it into another folder, then browse into that folder with Windows Explorer. From there, go into the `sitesroot` folder, then the `0` folder. You should now be looking at the root of your website (i.e., the files/folders that'll be copied to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` on the web server). Check the `bin` folder -- do you see the `FSharp.Data` assembly there? If not, this is a build/packaging problem, not a server problem; if you do see the `FSharp.Data` assembly, proceed to the next step.
- Deploy your project to Azure, then Remote Desktop into one of the instances your project is being hosted on. (There's a special procedure for enabling Remote Desktop on the instances -- if you haven't done this yet, you'll need to do so before continuing.) Once you're logged in, you can open *Event Viewer* (under *Administrative Tools*); look at the *Application* log under *Windows Logs* -- are there any ASP.NET errors there? If so, click them and look at the error message, it may contain a .NET exception message about not being able to resolve the `FSharp.Data` assembly. If it does, browse to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` and make sure `FSharp.Data` is in the `bin` folder of the website. If it is, proceed to the next step.
- If the `FSharp.Data` assembly is being packaged and deployed correctly along with your web project, then there could be some issue arising with it (or one of it's dependencies) being a .NET 4.0 assembly when your project is running on .NET 4.5. While logged in to the Azure instance (via Remote Desktop) you could enable Fusion logging and use the Fusion log viewer to trace how the CLR is attempting to load the assembly. If you do track down the issue, the likely way to fix it will be to add a `<bindingRedirect>` element within the `<dependentAssembly>` entry you created in your `web.config`. Here's how I did it to get the original F# PowerPack (which targeted the .NET 2.0 version of `FSharp.Core`) working in my F#/C# project on .NET 4.0:

  ```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  ```

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I had a go, but no joy.  I wonder if it's because the FSharp.Data library is a .NET 4.0 assembly, while my MVC project is a .NET 4.5 assembly.

Comment: @RobLyndon Did you get a different error message after adding the entry to your `web.config`? Also, did you set the target framework version of your F# project to .NET 4.5? The blog post linked in Pranav's comment says that the C#/F# MVC project template has a bug where the C# project will be set to target .NET 4.5, while the F# project will only be set to .NET 4.0 (so it needs to be changed manually).

Comment: It was the same error message, unfortunately.  Since I added my F# class library at a later stage, this isn't using the standard template, and everything is set to target 4.5.

Comment: @RobLyndon I've added some details about how I diagnosed the same/similar problem when I ran into it -- maybe it'll be useful in helping you track down the problem.