# F# compilation errors in Azure only when deployed from GitHub

Tags: azure, f#, kudu

I'm deploying a C# website to Azure from a GitHub repository. This website references a couple  of F# libraries and they compile just fine on my machine, but in Azure the build fails with a number of compilation errors.

Here is a snippet of the build log:

```
FS0001: A generic construct requires that the type 'Company' have a public default constructor [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\eureka-servicestack-poc\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Eureka.ServiceStack.FSharp.Poc\Services\Services.fsproj]
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\eureka-servicestack-poc\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Eureka.ServiceStack.FSharp.Poc\Services\CompaniesService.fs(28,17): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'PopulateWith' is not defined [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\eureka-servicestack-poc\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Eureka.ServiceStack.FSharp.Poc\Services\Services.fsproj]
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\eureka-servicestack-poc\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Eureka.ServiceStack.FSharp.Poc\Services\AppHost.fs(17,55): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\eureka-servicestack-poc\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Eureka.ServiceStack.FSharp.Poc\Services\Services.fsproj]
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

The first error should have been fixed after I put the CLIMutable attribute on the offending record type and the second error should have been fixed after including the proper namespace. I don't know what exactly the third error is about, especially since none of them happen locally.

To make sure I had the same version of F# in both places I've included the FSharp.Core dll in the solution and refer to the local version. This did not help but it removed a warning that it could not find version 4.3.1 of the file.

Is it possible that I'm running another version of the F# compiler and how do I check that? It has worked fine until now, which makes me suspect some slight difference in versioning of something. Unfortunately it seems quite hard to get insight into what actually happens in the build environment. It is a free website Azure website and it does not seem like you cen get direct access to it.

I could probably work around the individual issues for now but there seems to be a deeper issue at work here.

Comment: F# 4.3.1? Are you using VS2013?

Comment: This doesn't sound like exactly the same problem I answered in [Deployment of a web application using FSharp.Data to Azure Websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221978/deployment-of-a-web-application-using-fsharp-data-to-azure-websites/17225282#17225282), but reading that might give you some ideas about how to track down the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's VS 2013 RC. Does it come with a newer F# compiler than Azure has?

Comment: I tried building a deployment package as suggested in the linked question, but all the expected dlls were included.

Comment: Yes, VS2013 includes F# 3.1 and .NET 4.5.1. Since these are still RCs, I doubt Azure has been upgraded to support them yet (though I certainly could be wrong). Your best bet would be to use VS2012 (if possible) and make sure you're targeting .NET 4.0 in all of your projects (incl. your C# projects).

Comment: The F# projects build fine in VS 2012 on my local machine, so that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Some more reading material that may or may not be relevant to your issue: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/137 and https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/633. If you have a test repo you can share, maybe we can try to help investigate.

Comment: I've put together a repo here: https://github.com/clone1985/Eureka-C--POC. When I create a free website from this repo the build fails with some of the same compilation errors mentioned in the post. I also changed the F# project to use F# 3.0 instead of 3.1, but that did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with different versions of the F# compiler being used. Using Visual Studio 2013 RC, I was using the 3.1 version, which has had some [improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) causing my specific issues to not appear.

The problem was made difficult to identify because changing my F# project to use the 3.0 compiler in Visual Studio did not have any effect (it still compiled just fine). I even opened the solution up in Visual Studio 2012, and it all compiled well enough. It was only when I created a new project from scratch in VS 2012 that I began to get the same compilation errors as on the server. So I guess that this must be an error (or at least not very desirable feature) in the project file that was created. I'm not sure if this should be classified as a bug with VS 2013, especially since I don't know exactly what causes the error.

So the simple solution until Azure (or is this a Kudu thing?) supports the 3.1 compiler is to either recreate the project file in VS 2012 or to copy code which does not compile over to a test solution where fixes can be tested.

Comment: Surely it must be possible to retrofit the changes into a project created in VS 2013? What changes did you observe between the projects created in different versions?

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't see anything obvious. So far I have just accepted that I might get compiler errors when pushing to the cloud, and have not spent more time experimenting with the project files, but that should be simple for anyone to do if they are interested.